# How to prevent view from disappearing when requesting photo access?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

A `UIViewController` tries to present a `UIImagePickerController` and the app hasn't requested permission to access the photo gallery yet.

So before presenting the `UIImagePickerController` iOS displays a `UIAlertController` to ask the user to allow or deny access to photos. However the previously visible view is already removed so the alert is displayed over the underlying view controller's view.

How can I prevent the current view from begin removed or at least prevent the underlying view from being visible when the alert is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out:

The `UIImagePickerController` has to have its property `modalPresentationStyle` set to an `.Over...` value so the underlying screen does not disappear after the transition is complete.

So instead of

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
```

it should be set to one of those

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
self.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext  // In this case also set `definesPresentationContext = true` for the presenting view controller.
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle):

> **OverFullScreen:** A view presentation style in which the presented view
>   covers the screen. The views beneath the presented content are not
>   removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation finishes. So if
>   the presented view controller does not fill the screen with opaque
>   content, **the underlying content shows through**.